# created an key frame animation in Blender without bones but i don't know how to use it in Three.js.(i know to deal with bones)

Tags: html, three.js, blender

It's just a model to show the boneless animation. I want to know in which format to export because I'm unable to export this kind of animation in .json

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to migrate this question the http://blender.stackexchange.com Stack Exchange site for more Blender-related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models), I'd recommend using [glTF-Blender-Exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter). It does support this type of animation. You can then load the result in [THREE.GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader).